# How to fetch data from URL using $_GET in php

Tags: php, mysqli, get

I am trying to implement a password reset functionality. Here is my code

**index.php**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method = "POST">

        <input type = "email" name = "recover_email" placeholder = "Enter Your Email Address" required/>                    
        <input type = "submit" name= "recover" value = "Recover"/>

</form>

<?php     

    if(isset($_POST['recover']) && $_POST['recover'] == 'Recover'){
        $email = $_POST['recover_email'];

        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * from registered_users where email = ?");
        $sql->bind_param("s",$email);
        $sql->execute();
        $sql = $sql->get_result();

        if(($getRowCount = $sql->num_rows) == 1){ 
                $rowName = $sql->fetch_assoc();

                $code = rand(1000, 1000000);

        mail();

$updateCode = $db->prepare("UPDATE registered_users SET passwordResetCode = ? where email=?");
                 $updateCode->bind_param("is",$code,$email);
                 $updateCode->execute();
                 $updateCodeResult = $updateCode->get_result();
            }   

    }else if(!(($getRowCount = $sql->num_rows) == 1) && $email != ''){
       //do something
      }
    }

    ?>
```

**Email body being sent:**

```
http://www.website.com/passwordreset.php?code=$code&email=$email
```

The mail, sql update and the link details are being sent fine.

Now I try to update the password clicking on the link on my next page.

**passwordreset.php**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method = "POST">

     <table cellpadding = "5%" style="width:70%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type = "password" id="newPassword" name = "newPassword" placeholder = "New Password" minlength="8" required />
          </td>
        </tr> 

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input  type = "password" id= "confirmnewPassword" name = "confirmnewPassword" placeholder = "Confirm New Password" minlength="8" required />
          </td>                    
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type = "submit" name= "setNewPassword" value = "Set Password"/> 
          </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
   </form>

<?php

    if(isset($_GET['code'])){

        $getEmail = $_GET['email'];
        $getCode = $_GET['code'];

        if(isset($_POST['setNewPassword']) && $_POST['setNewPassword'] == 'Set Password'){

        $newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
        $confirmNewPassword = $_POST['confirmnewPassword'];         

        if($newPassword == $confirmNewPassword){

        $updatePassword = $db->prepare("UPDATE registered_users SET password = ?, re_password = ? where email = ? and passwordResetCode = ?");
        $updatePassword->bind_param("sssi",$newPassword,$confirmNewPassword,$getEmail,$getCode);
        $updatePassword->execute();     

        }else if($newPassword != $confirmNewPassword){
        }
        }           
    }   
    ?>
```

If I remove all the $_GET functionality from this code, it works fine, but it seems that $_GET does not fetch my email and code from the url at all.

Comment: use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] instead of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in passwordreset.php

Comment: on the passwordreset.php page? or the previous one?

Comment: On passwordreset.php

Comment: Within each if statement use an echo to establish which part the code may be failing at. Also, try querying the SQL statement by itself, without the validation and input the values manually to make sure there's nothing wrong with your query. Without seeing the database schema it's kind of hard to get the full picture, but from what I can see your code looks fine.

Comment: why is there extra `{` before `else if` in `index.php`,can you please explain.

Comment: @Rakesh : that worked for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your script does the following.
1.Redirecting to The Password reset page with the arguments.
2.Get the post to reset the password ( but doesnt get the arguments)
You have to store the get until the user posts the new password

```
if(isset($_GET["code"])){
session_start();
$_SESSION["code"]=$_GET["code"];
}
```

When the user posts his new password, access it.

```
session_start();
$code=$_SESSION["code"];
```